# Limit of methods 64K per a dex file in Android

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I faced with this problem `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536` and I decided to exclude some methods from a dex file. My gradle.build:

```
compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:+') {
        exclude group: "com.google.android.gms.analytics"
        exclude group: "com.google.android.gms.games"
        exclude group: "com.google.android.gms.plus"
        exclude group: "com.google.android.gms.drive"
        exclude group: "com.google.android.gms.ads"
    }
```

I think that this snippet of code is wrong, because there is error `method ID not in [0, 0xffff]...`. How can I exclude unnecessary parts of Google Play Service? I use only maps and GCM.

**Updated.**

Thanks reVerse. It's really useful code. There is a script for getting count of methods (also can see names of existing packages) https://gist.github.com/JakeWharton/6002797 (`source ./dex.sh; dex-method-count-by-package test.apk`)

Before using the snippet of code from reVerse's answer

```
Count of methods / Package
...
22484   com.google.android.gms
2   com.google.android.gms.actions
578 com.google.android.gms.ads
152 com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick
25  com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier
86  com.google.android.gms.ads.internal
86  com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.rawhtmlad
86  com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.rawhtmlad.client
88  com.google.android.gms.ads.mediation
4   com.google.android.gms.ads.mediation.admob
73  com.google.android.gms.ads.mediation.customevent
26  com.google.android.gms.ads.purchase
118 com.google.android.gms.ads.search
...
858 com.google.android.gms.games.internal.api
43  com.google.android.gms.games.internal.constants
8   com.google.android.gms.games.internal.data
31  com.google.android.gms.games.internal.events
9   com.google.android.gms.games.internal.experience
215 com.google.android.gms.games.internal.game
56  com.google.android.gms.games.internal.multiplayer
23  com.google.android.gms.games.internal.notification
80  com.google.android.gms.games.internal.player
86  com.google.android.gms.games.internal.request
...
```

After using the snippet of code from reVerse's answer, packages: ads, games and etc were deleted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Update - Google Play Services 6.5 (12-08-14)

With version 6.5 Google finally unbundled the Google Play Services. So from now on it'll be possible to selectively compile the APIs into your executable.

#### Example (only using AdMob and Android Wear APIs)

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:6.5.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:6.5.+'
```

For all the other individual Google Play Services APIs check [this page on d.android.com](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#split).

**Note:** Using the `+` is typically discouraged. As of now the current correct version would be `6.5.87`. For more information see the [official Blog-Post (click)](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2014/12/google-play-services-and-dex-method.html).

---

Some time ago there's been an article on *Medium.com* called ["[DEX] Sky’s the limit? No, 65K methods is"](https://medium.com/@rotxed/dex-skys-the-limit-no-65k-methods-is-28e6cb40cf71) (definitely worth a read), which describes a way to **strip** the **Google Play Services** with a shell-script which you can find [here (google-play-services-strip-script)](https://gist.github.com/dextorer/a32cad7819b7f272239b).
While this is an option, there's also a **gradle task** which does this for you:

```
def toCamelCase(String string) {
    String result = ""
    string.findAll("[^\\W]+") { String word ->
        result += word.capitalize()
    }
    return result
}

afterEvaluate { project ->
    Configuration runtimeConfiguration = project.configurations.getByName('compile')
    ResolutionResult resolution = runtimeConfiguration.incoming.resolutionResult
// Forces resolve of configuration
    ModuleVersionIdentifier module = resolution.getAllComponents().find { it.moduleVersion.name.equals("play-services") }.moduleVersion

    String prepareTaskName = "prepare${toCamelCase("${module.group} ${module.name} ${module.version}")}Library"
    File playServiceRootFolder = project.tasks.find { it.name.equals(prepareTaskName) }.explodedDir

    Task stripPlayServices = project.tasks.create(name: 'stripPlayServices', group: "Strip") {
        inputs.files new File(playServiceRootFolder, "classes.jar")
        outputs.dir playServiceRootFolder
        description 'Strip useless packages from Google Play Services library to avoid reaching dex limit'

        doLast {
            copy {
                from(file(new File(playServiceRootFolder, "classes.jar")))
                into(file(playServiceRootFolder))
                rename { fileName ->
                    fileName = "classes_orig.jar"
                }
            }
            tasks.create(name: "stripPlayServices" + module.version, type: Jar) {
                destinationDir = playServiceRootFolder
                archiveName = "classes.jar"
                from(zipTree(new File(playServiceRootFolder, "classes_orig.jar"))) {
  ----->                // Specify what should be removed
                }
            }.execute()
            delete {
                delete (file(new File(playServiceRootFolder, "classes_orig.jar")))
            }
        }
    }

    project.tasks.findAll { it.name.startsWith('prepare') && it.name.endsWith('Dependencies') }.each { Task task ->
        task.dependsOn stripPlayServices
    }
}
```

**Note:** This is taken from [Gradle task to strip unused packages on Google Play Services library @GitHubGist](https://gist.github.com/dmarcato/d7c91b94214acd936e42)

The relevant part for you is where the arrow is in the `task.create(...)`. There you need to specify which parts should be removed. So in your case just write something like this in there:

```
exclude "com/google/ads/**"
exclude "com/google/android/gms/analytics/**"
exclude "com/google/android/gms/games/**"
exclude "com/google/android/gms/panorama/**"
exclude "com/google/android/gms/plus/**"
exclude "com/google/android/gms/drive/**"
exclude "com/google/android/gms/ads/**"
exclude "com/google/android/gms/wallet/**"
exclude "com/google/android/gms/wearable/**"
```

This will remove everything except the Maps- and GCM-Part.

**Note:** In order to use it, just copy the contents of the gradle-task to the bottom of the `build.gradle` file of your app module.