# How to adapt Android App to use Retrofit without multiDex

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-multidex

I have an Android project that would benefit from using Retrofit. It's still in very early stages and there are less than a dozen function and class definitions. As soon as I add Retrofit to Gradle, I have a DexIndexOverflowException.

It seems way too early to add multiDex to the project, especially since it seems to be triggered by the addition of one dependency. Surely, I must be doing something wrong since there basic examples don't appear to require multiDex. What should I be doing differently?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mydomain.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        //multiDexEnabled  true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),     'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-beta1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0-beta1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    //compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    //compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***The solution:***

Remove the Google Play Services API dependency and only include the specific Google Play Services API dependencies as needed. I removed:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
```

***The reason:***

The DEX file hold class definitions and adjunct data for your app including its dependencies. There need to be multiple DEX files if there are > 64K methods, including Android framework methods and library methods.

**A brand new app starts out with a lot of methods.**
I don't know how many methods are included in the Android framework, but it's a lot and I'm sure it's thousands to tens of thousands.
I don't know how many methods are included in Google Play Services, but [rumor has it to be over 28k](http://blog.safedk.com/technology/reducing-your-method-count-the-google-play-services-edition/).

Between the Android framework and Google Play Services, there's probably not room for more than a few thousand more methods.

[Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) is an abstraction layer built on top of [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/). OkHttp covers a lot of things including SPDY, HTTP/2, encryption, connection pooling, etc. and has dependencies on lots of Java frameworks. Any framework that covers something so extensively is going to have many methods. In my situation, it has enough to push past the 64K barrier. It's probably a reasonable amount.

**Compile only necessary methods from Google Play Services** [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25608736) to a similar problem revealed that you can import only the APIs needed from Google Play Services very easily in the Gradle configuration. See [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) for more information.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, I had the same problem. If you want to use Retrofit with multiDex, and you want to keep Google Play Service in your project to use its APIs, follow the steps below:

1- Keep `multiDexEnabled true` on your Gradle

2- Add this dependency in your Gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

3- Create this class:

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.multidex.MultiDex;

public class MultiDexApplication extends Application {

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
}
```

4- On your AndroidManifest.xml add:

```
<application
    android:name=".MultiDexApplication"
...
</application>
```

And now, try to recompile your project. I'm using version 8.3.0 of Google Play Service, and version 2.1.0 of Retrofit and Gson in my Gradle.